ggplot with stat_n_text with n for subgroups
Good afternoon,
I am trying to add the n for each of the subgroups in females and males (not just for the total in male (n=107) and female (n=94)). However, I havent found a way to do so:
The following code is used to generate the plot below:
stat.test <- metadata %>%
  wilcox_test(air_quality ~ sex) %>%
  add_significance()

p1<-ggplot(data = metadata, aes(x=sex, y=air_quality)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=subgroups),show.legend = TRUE) 
stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "sex")

p2<-p1+ stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.01, 0.1)))

p3<-p2+ stat_n_text( y.pos =0.05) + labs(x ="Sex", y = "Air quality")+labs(title = "Airquality")
p3


Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Update after adding the suggested solution below from M:


Update 2 with dummy data:
## Create some dummy data

metadata <- data.frame(sex = sample(c("M", "F"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                       subgroups = sample(c("1", "2","3"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                       air_quality = sample(0:100,100, replace = TRUE))


# Is air_quality an issue?
metadata$air_quality <- as.numeric(as.character(metadata$air_quality))

stat.test <- metadata %>%
  wilcox_test(air_quality ~ sex) %>%
  add_significance()

# boxplot
p1 <- ggplot(data = metadata, aes(x = sex, y = air_quality)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = subgroups), show.legend = TRUE)

# p-values
stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "sex")

# p-value plot
p2 <- p1 + stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.01, 0.1)))

# Count data for labels
n_data <- metadata %>%
  group_by(sex, subgroups) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop')

# Dynamic stuff
n_data <- n_data %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  mutate(max_y = max(metadata$air_quality[metadata$sex == sex], na.rm = TRUE) + 0.1)

p3 <- p2 + 
  geom_text(data = n_data, aes(x = sex, y = max_y, label = paste("n =", n), group = subgroups),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.1), size = 3, color = "blue") +
  labs(x = "Sex", y = "Air Quality") + 
  labs(title = "Air Quality by Gender and Subgroup")

p3



Update 3 including final solution with statistical test
# Dummy data
set.seed(123)  # set random seed!!
metadata <- data.frame(
  sex = sample(c("M", "F"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  subgroups = sample(c("1", "2", "3"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  air_quality = sample(0:100, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

stat.test <- metadata %>%
  wilcox_test(air_quality ~ sex) %>%
  add_significance()


# Boxplot
p <- ggplot(metadata, aes(x = sex, y = air_quality)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = subgroups)) +
  labs(x = "Sex", y = "Air Quality", title = "Air Quality by Gender and Subgroup")

# p-values
stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "sex")

# p-value plot
p <- p + stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.01, 0.1)))

# Counts and subgroups
n_data <- metadata %>%
  group_by(sex, subgroups) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  mutate(y_pos = max(metadata$air_quality[metadata$sex == first(sex)]) + 5)

# Total counts for each gender
total_n <- metadata %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(total = n()) %>%
  mutate(y_pos = max(metadata$air_quality) + 15)  # Position above subgroup counts

# "stack the plot"
p <- p +
  # Subgroup counts
  geom_text(data = n_data,
            aes(x = sex, y = y_pos, label = paste("n =", n), group = subgroups),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.75),
            size = 4,
            color = "red") +
  # Total counts per gender
  geom_text(data = total_n,
            aes(x = sex, y = y_pos, label = paste("Group n =", total)),
            size = 5,
            color = "blue")

p



ggplot2 is cool and logical. There isn't an equivalent "cool and logical" for Python.
Here is the answer minus the statistical overlay (library loading issue),
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Dummy data
set.seed(123)  # set random seed!!
metadata <- data.frame(
    sex = sample(c("M", "F"), 100, replace = TRUE),
    subgroups = sample(c("1", "2", "3"), 100, replace = TRUE),
    air_quality = sample(0:100, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

# Boxplot
p <- ggplot(metadata, aes(x = sex, y = air_quality)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = subgroups)) +
    labs(x = "Sex", y = "Air Quality", title = "Air Quality by Gender and Subgroup")

# Counts and subgroups
n_data <- metadata %>%
    group_by(sex, subgroups) %>%
    summarise(n = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
    group_by(sex) %>%
    mutate(y_pos = max(metadata$air_quality[metadata$sex == first(sex)]) + 5)

# Total counts for each gender
total_n <- metadata %>%
    group_by(sex) %>%
    summarise(total = n()) %>%
    mutate(y_pos = max(metadata$air_quality) + 15)  # Position above subgroup counts

# "stack the plot"
p <- p +
    # Subgroup counts
    geom_text(data = n_data,
              aes(x = sex, y = y_pos, label = paste("n =", n), group = subgroups),
              position = position_dodge(width = 0.75),
              size = 4,
              color = "red") +
    # Total counts per gender
    geom_text(data = total_n,
              aes(x = sex, y = y_pos, label = paste("Group n =", total)),
              size = 5,
              color = "blue")

print(p)

# Save it
ggsave("air_quality_plot.pdf", p)


Is this ok? I dunno why I'd got a stats library loading issue, but R ... its not my favourite.

Thank you very much. However the numbers are going on top of each other, any idea how I could fix this? Thanks again ! (see picture  in original post)

Thank you so much for your answer. I get the following error messagen:Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: max_y = +....
ℹ In group 1: sex = "FEMALE".
Caused by error in Summary.factor():
! 'max' not meaningful for factors

@Bine done minus the statistical overlay ... stats package issue.

Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for. I added the statistical test in the final solution above. Thanks again for your help very appreciated, happy new year!
